# Get current user name under Windows

Tags: c, windows

How can I get the current users sign in name in Windows?

What I have figured out is the function

```
char* user_name;
user_name=getenv("USERNAME");
```

but the problem is that it gives

```
admin
```

but when I sign in to Windows, my user name is "Sudip" and not "admin".

Comment: Sudip, sorry `USER` is the env variable for *nix like OS's, but `getenv_s` part is still valid, I deleted my answer because it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Try `getenv("LOGNAME")`

Comment: `LOGNAME` too doesn't work. I have seen environment variables in system settings and there is no `LOGNAME` or anything that contains user name.

Comment: @jongware I have seen that question twice before posting this. There's no answer to this question

Comment: You should have mentioned, then, that *none* of the offered solutions worked -- including `GetUserName`.

Comment: What does `whoami` return when you run it in the command prompt?

Comment: I looked most of the settings, and found that when I Log in with Microsoft account, the Name is changed according to username for Microsoft Account in User account. but when I looked in lusrmgr.msc, the username was still admin.

Comment: @SudipBhattarai That sounds right - "sudip" is also your computer name, given the results of running `whoami`. When you log in with your Microsoft account, it uses your name there as the display name (which you can change in your profile) for your account, but the underlying account will have a fixed name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetUserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
```

Comment: The output for `printf("%s",username)` is `admin` again.

Comment: Are you running your program as administrator?

Comment: no. I am just logged in with administrator previllage account.

Comment: I have admin previllege, but it gives me correct output on my win7.

Comment: If "admin" is what GetUserName returns, then that's almost certainly what your username is.  What do you get if you type `net user admin` at the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetUserNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) to get your display name instead of the actual user name. The [EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration has a `NameDisplay` entry that should do what you want.